# Google App Engine Data Store Model Reference Another Class

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

So that you can understand the data model, I basically have cities and within each one I'll have categories and then inside each category I'll have listings.  Here's what I have so far.

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class City(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    connections = db.ListProperty()
    categories = db.ListProperty()
```

So Next, I want to add:

```
class Category(db.Model)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

But do I need to specify that only Category should be in categories or something to that effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to throw the `categories` property from your `City` and use a `ReferenceProperty` in your `Category` class:

```
class Category(db.Model)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    city = db.ReferenceProperty(City, collection_name = 'categories')
```

This will also automatically add `categories` collection for your `City` model.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at a custom property named KeyListProperty in [App Engine Patch](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/wiki/RagendjaDB). That will give you the sort of many-to-many relationship you want.