# Differing ways of inputting categories into Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

I'm looking for the smartest/various way of handling categories in App Engine. I see two approaches:

[Google App Engine Data Store Model Reference Another Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107660/google-app-engine-data-store-model-reference-another-class)

using way A:

```
 companycategory = db.ReferenceProperty(mycategories, collection_name = 'categories')
```

from the example in the url:

```
class Category(db.Model)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    city = db.ReferenceProperty(City, collection_name = 'categories')
```

and way B:

```
companycategory = db.CategoryProperty(default="A", choices=["A", "AA", "B", "C"], required=True)
```

Is there anything else to consider. A uses a table and another object model which seems overkill, but way B puts text into fields which means typo's might well creep in. Short of putting integers into the category field and manually referencing is there a smart way to do anything else? Or do I bite the bullet with a another model/table?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out [taggable-mixin](http://code.google.com/p/taggable-mixin/) for another option.

The "smartest" way to handle categories in AppEngine varies depending on your use-case.

Do you have a pre-defined list of categories or do you allow your users to add their own categories dynamically? The best answer may differ depending on your particular case.

In most cases with AppEngine, you usually would want to go with the "de-normalized" option. It saves you money in terms of datastore writes and reads. And because it does less writes and reads, it's also faster.

You may also use `db.StringListProperty()` instead of `db.CategoryProperty()` to allow a company to be filed under multiple categories.

If you know what your possible categories are ahead of time, I would do something similar to this:

```
class Company(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    category = db.StringListProperty() #to allow multiple categories

#Creating a company
company = Company()
company.name = "XYZ Car Rental Corporation"
company.category = ["NEW YORK","CAR RENTAL", "CORPORATION"] #City and Company Category. I would make them all uppercase to prevent case-sensitive/typo issues.
company.put()

#querying
query = Company.all()
query.filter('category',"NEW YORK")
results = query.fetch(10)  #this returns Company entities with "NEW YORK" in their category list

#You can also do multiple categories (AND)
query = Company.all()
query.filter('category',"NEW YORK")
query.filter('category',"CORPORATION")
results = query.fetch(10)  #this returns Company entities with "NEW YORK" and "CORPORATION" in their category list
```

If your users create categories dynamically, and there are relatively few (less than 1000) entities to be under a certain category, I would recommend [taggable-mixin](http://code.google.com/p/taggable-mixin/).

Comment: @Dave: If you are starting out fresh, you may want to consider using the newer NDB module in place of the DB: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/. Also, since you were worried about typos and such, you can create a separate storage for all valid categories and check input against that, to ensure that what is stored is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. I guess one of my complication is the Django framework. The string way whilst not as elegant as keys would work well for this usecase. However I'm having trouble with the Django template, I get the following error: `code`BadValueError: Property companycategory is ['B', 'i', 'o']; must be one of ['Bio', 'Pharm', 'I', ''] `code`when I used the following `code` companycategory = db.StringListProperty(default="Bio", choices=["Bio", "Pharm", "I", "S"], required=True) `code`

Comment: @Dave: Change the default="Bio" to default=["Bio"]. StringListProperty expects a list of strings (even a list of one string will do), but not a string.